# Laravel how to check if two conditions are validate in controller

Tags: php, laravel

Im new in laravel and wanted to redirect customers to specific page if this condition is valid but there is problem can you help me

```
 if (Customer::where(('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id)&&('package_id'==2))->exists()){

return view('index.customer.customerabout');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if(Customer::where('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id)->where('package_id', 2)->count() > 1) {

    // .......

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple where statements for and condition. For OR condition you can use orWhere. To check if it exists you should check if count is greater than 0.

```
if(Customer::where('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id)->where('package_id', 2)->count() > 0) {
// your code here 
}
```

if you want to use OR operator you can do this

```
if(Customer::where('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id)->orWhere('package_id', 2)->count() > 0) {
// your code here 
}
```